# Form Validation Becomes Invalid After One Letter

Tags: html, validation

i have a contact form where I ask for ppls names. i tried to put some validation to make sure they only used letters "[A-Za-z]". if i type in 1 letter it goes to valid but then if i type any more letters it says invalid. is there something else i need to add to "[A-Za-z]"?

```
                <div class="form-group">
                   <label class="col-xs-4 control-label" for="lname">Last Name</label>
                   <div class="col-xs-8">
                      <input id="lname" name="lname" type="text" placeholder="Your last name" data-trigger="manual" data-content="Can only contain letters!" class="name form-control" type="text" required pattern="[A-Za-z]">
                  </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Do you really want to restrict people’s names to containing only letters A–Z and a–z? What will de Broglie, Brontë, and Strauß do?

Comment: btw, you have type="text" in there twice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The meaning of your pattern value is "only one character".

for using letters you can use pattern value as pattern="[A-Za-z]+". The meaning of + is 1 or more characters.

Answer (score 0):

The attribute `pattern="[A-Za-z]"` means that the value must be a single letter. Add the `+` operator to allow repetition: `pattern="[A-Za-z]+"`. The `pattern` attribute values have the same syntax as [regular expressions in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

On the other hand, you probably should not use `pattern` at all for a person’s name, *unless* you have a good reason to restrict them so that people are forced to enter their names as modified (e.g. omitting diacritic marks, omitting spaces, hyphens, and apostrophes, and transcribing characters that are not in the Latin alphabet).